# При объединении двух DataFrame появляются дубликаты

Tags: python, pandas

Есть два DataFrame:

```
df1
   carNumber    last_name  first_name      tel_drv
0  м599ео89     Максимов      Сергей  79888888888
1  к595ум89     Шердаков        Илья  79999999999
2  м055ун89       Иванов   Александр  77979879879
3  м599ео89  Игамбердиев        Исак  77789746566
4  н100ан89      Гученко       Антон  79132131321
5  к584ум89   Пучеглазов       Денис  79879877979

df2
 carNumber   carBrand     carModel     carColor  carType carYear
0  м599ео89      Chery        Tiggo      Красный   Эконом    2014
1  к595ум89  Chevrolet        Cruze        Серый   Эконом    2013
2  м055ун89       Ford  GRAND C-MAX       Чёрный   Эконом    2006
3  м599ео89    Hyundai       Sonata      Бежевый   Эконом    2007
4  м904во89    Hyundai      Solaris      Голубой   Эконом    2013
5  е585св89    Hyundai      Solaris  Серебристый  Комфорт    2014
```

Объединяю таблицы по `carNumber`:

```
df_drv_car = df1.merge(df2, how='left')
```

Но в DataFrame `df_drv_car` появляются дубликаты. Что делаю не так?

Мне надо:

```
df_drv_car 
  carNumber    last_name  first_name      tel_drv   carBrand     carModel     carColor  carType carYear
0  м599ео89     Максимов      Сергей  79888888888      Chery        Tiggo      Красный   Эконом    2014
1  к595ум89     Шердаков        Илья  79999999999  Chevrolet        Cruze        Серый   Эконом    2013
и т.д.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так работает декартово произведение множеств. Если у вас есть дубликаты в обоих множествах, то в результируещем множестве будут все комбинации:

```
In [22]: df1
Out[22]:
   id  val
0   1    1
1   2    2         # id: 2
2   2   22         # id: 2
3   3    3

In [23]: df2
Out[23]:
   id       name
0   2        two   # id: 2
1   2  two_again   # id: 2
2   4       four
```

---

```
In [24]: df1.merge(df2)
Out[24]:
   id  val       name
0   2    2        two
1   2    2  two_again
2   2   22        two
3   2   22  two_again
```

---

тоже самое происходит с вашими таблицами:

```
In [28]: df1.merge(df2).sort_values("carNumber")
Out[28]:
  carNumber    last_name first_name      tel_drv   carBrand     carModel carColor carType  carYear
4  к595ум89     Шердаков       Илья  79999999999  Chevrolet        Cruze    Серый  Эконом     2013
5  м055ун89       Иванов  Александр  77979879879       Ford  GRAND_C-MAX   Чёрный  Эконом     2006
0  м599ео89     Максимов     Сергей  79888888888      Chery        Tiggo  Красный  Эконом     2014
1  м599ео89     Максимов     Сергей  79888888888    Hyundai       Sonata  Бежевый  Эконом     2007
2  м599ео89  Игамбердиев       Исак  77789746566      Chery        Tiggo  Красный  Эконом     2014
3  м599ео89  Игамбердиев       Исак  77789746566    Hyundai       Sonata  Бежевый  Эконом     2007
```

Comment: действительно были дубликаты во второй таблице. Убрал их и все стало отлично. Спасибо.