# Как правильно соединить два DataFrame разного размера?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join, анализ-данных

Eсть два DataFrame:

```
new_big_df
21571 rows × 64 columns
```

и

```
car_new_features
1554 rows × 8 columns
```

---

```
In [114]: new_big_df
Out[114]:
       body_type     color fuel_type  model_date_begin         name series  ...  covid    price dataset  luxury_tax  car_tax  equipments_count
0      hatchback     black  gasoline              2007         130i    1ER  ...      1   591500   train         1.0    34980                 2
1      cabriolet       red  gasoline              2007         120i    1ER  ...      1  1046500   train         1.0     6552                 0
2      hatchback     olive  gasoline              2004         118i    1ER  ...      1   500500   train         1.0     3096                 9
3      hatchback  mid_blue  gasoline              2011        M135i    1ER  ...      1  1428700   train         1.0    42240                 0
4      hatchback     black  gasoline              2011         116i    1ER  ...      1   599690   train         1.0     3264                 8
...          ...       ...       ...               ...          ...    ...  ...    ...      ...     ...         ...      ...               ...
21566      sedan     black  gasoline              2013         520i    5ER  ...      0        0    test         1.0     7912                13
21567    allroad     black    diesel              2013          30d     X5  ...      0        0    test         1.0    16932                18
21568      sedan     black  gasoline              2002        525xi    5ER  ...      0        0    test         1.0    12644                 6
21569      sedan     brown  gasoline              2009  528i xDrive    5ER  ...      0        0    test         1.0    16660                13
21570    allroad     black  gasoline              2007          50i     X6  ...      0        0    test         1.0    53724                 1

[21571 rows x 64 columns]

In [115]: car_new_features
Out[115]:
              name  weight  dimensions_length  dimensions_width  dimensions_height  model_date_begin  body_type series
0            M140i    1510               4329              1765               1430              2017  hatchback    1ER
1             118i    1380               4329              1765               1440              2017  hatchback    1ER
2       118i Sport    1380               4329              1765               1440              2017  hatchback    1ER
3       118i Urban    1380               4329              1765               1440              2017  hatchback    1ER
4     118i М Sport    1380               4329              1765               1440              2017  hatchback    1ER
...            ...     ...                ...               ...                ...               ...        ...    ...
1549        3.2i M    1495               4113              1781               1271              2006      coupe     Z4
1550          2.0i    1295               4091              1781               1299              2002  cabriolet     Z4
1551          2.5i    1335               4091              1781               1299              2002  cabriolet     Z4
1552          3.0i    1365               4091              1781               1299              2002  cabriolet     Z4
1553           5.0    1660               4400              1830               1317              2000  cabriolet     Z8

[1554 rows x 8 columns]
```

Мне надо для каждого наблюдения (строки) из большого `new_big_df` взять из меньшего датасета `car_new_features` недостающие в `new_big_df` параметры, при условии, если `new_big_df` совпадают с `car_new_features` по следующим признакам (колонкам) одновременно: 'name', 'series', 'model_date_begin', 'body_type'

То есть, должен получиться новый DataFrame, у которого количество наблюдений (строк) такое же, как у большого `new_big_df`, но для каждого наблюдения нужно расширить теми признаками (колонками), которые есть в малом датасете `car_new_features`

Такая команда не привела к желаемому результату:

```
result = new_big_df.merge(car_new_features, how='left', on=['name', 'series', 'model_date_begin', 'body_type'])
```

Comment: `Такая команда не привела к желаемому результату` - а к какому результату привела? Можете выложить воспроизводимые примеры данных?

Comment: Куда выложить ноутбук с кодом и данными?

Comment: Если вкратце, то после result = new_big_df.merge(car_new_features, on=['name', 'series', 'model_date_begin', 'body_type']) получаю объем Int64Index: 15934 entries, 68 columns

А после result = new_big_df.merge(car_new_features, how='left', on=['name', 'series', 'model_date_begin', 'body_type']) -  28272 entries, 68 columns

А надо, чтобы было 21571 наблюдений (строк) и 68 колонок-признаков

Comment: Похоже у вас есть дубликаты и это приводит к подобным проблемам. [связанный вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1119311/211923)

Comment: Дубликаты были и правда. Спасибо за подсказку. Но проблему это не решило. Обе команды, которые выше в комментарии применял раньше, привели к аналогичному результату.

Comment: Можете выложить воспроизводимые примеры данных на какой-нибудь файлообменник?

Comment: Да, пожалуйста, - https://fex.net/ru/s/ef0abop

Comment: @ViktorAndriichuk Пожалуйста, замените картинки в вопросе текстом (плюс пока авансом).

Comment: @0xdb, я бы заменил и в будущем вставлял текстом, если бы знал как вставить текст сюда таким образом, чтобы он смотрелся как картинка (в смысле был так же нагляден). подскажете?

Comment: @ViktorAndriichuk  А какие сложности? Посмотрите в ответе, там же результат текстом. Копи-паста и отмечаете вставленное кодом.

Comment: @0xdb, ну, я так и делал, но оно вышло не так, как в комментарии ниже. можете глянуть сейчас - я поменял.

Comment: @ViktorAndriichuk У вас там табы вместо пробелов, поэтому всё криво. Надо в инструменте настроить замещение табуляторов пробелами. Подождите, может автор ответа вам поможет как вернётся. Ниже это не комментарий, это ответ, не путайте.

Comment: @MaxU ^^^ Не сможете помочь ТС с оформлением данных текстом?

Comment: @MaxU, спасибо! )

Comment: @MaxU совсем другое дело, спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблему невозможно решить пока вы не избавитесь от дубликатов в `car_new_features`, т.к. одной и той же модели из `new_big_df` будет соответствовать несколько строк из `car_new_features` и, объединяя два фрейма, Pandas может только сделать [декартово произведение множеств](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1119311/211923).

Пример дубликатов:

```
on = ['name', 'series', 'model_date_begin', 'body_type']

In [65]: car_new_features[car_new_features.duplicated(subset=on)].sort_values(on).head(19)
Out[65]:
      name  weight  dimensions_length  dimensions_width  dimensions_height  model_date_begin  body_type series
1513   1.9    1295               4025              1692               1288              1996  cabriolet     Z3
1514   1.9    1315               4025              1692               1288              1996  cabriolet     Z3
1505   1.9    1295               4025              1692               1288              1999  cabriolet     Z3
1506   1.9    1315               4025              1692               1288              1999  cabriolet     Z3
124   116i    1310               4239              1748               1421              2007  hatchback    1ER
135   116i    1340               4239              1748               1421              2007  hatchback    1ER
137   116i    1365               4239              1748               1421              2007  hatchback    1ER
63    116i    1385               4324              1765               1462              2011  hatchback    1ER
64    116i    1385               4324              1765               1462              2011  hatchback    1ER
47    116i    1305               4324              1765               1462              2012  hatchback    1ER
149   118i    1335               4227              1751               1430              2004  hatchback    1ER
126   118i    1365               4239              1748               1421              2007  hatchback    1ER
136   118i    1350               4239              1748               1421              2007  hatchback    1ER
138   118i    1375               4239              1748               1421              2007  hatchback    1ER
102   118i    1505               4360              1748               1411              2008  cabriolet    1ER
93    118i    1520               4360              1748               1411              2011  cabriolet    1ER
24    118i    1380               4329              1765               1440              2015  hatchback    1ER
30    118i    1395               4329              1765               1440              2015  hatchback    1ER
7     118i    1395               4329              1765               1440              2017  hatchback    1ER
```

Какой, например, вес должен выбрать Pandas для

```
{
  "name": "116i", 
  "series": "1ER", 
  "model_date_begin": 2007, 
  "body_type": "hatchback"
}
```

???

---

Без дубликатов в `car_new_features`, все работает правильно:

```
on = ['name', 'series', 'model_date_begin', 'body_type']
result = new_big_df.merge(car_new_features.drop_duplicates(subset=on), how='left', on=on)
```

---

результат:

```
In [71]: new_big_df.shape
Out[71]: (21571, 64)
```

Comment: Да, так сработало. Большое спасибо!